# R, convert multiple text filenames to a column name

Tags: r, text, data.table

I've got many text files with named by year i.e. yob1940.txt,yob1941.txt. Each file has 3 colums of data. I'm trying to import the data into R in a single data table, and add the year for each file in a 4th column.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Lots of questions about this. You'll need functions `list.files`, `do.call`, `sapply` or `lapply`. Not necessarily in that order. :)

Answer (score 0):

Smth like this will work:

```
rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern = "yob[0-9]+\\.txt"),
                 function(x) data.table(year = sub('.*?([0-9]+).*', '\\1', x),
                                        fread(x)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read these files as x1 and x2

```
df.list<-list(x1,x2)
kk<-do.call(rbind,df.list)
year<-data.frame(rep(c(1940,1941),c(nrow(x1),nrow(x2))))
names(year)<-"year"
mydata<-data.frame(cbind(kk,year))
```

A sample example:

```
x1<-data.frame(x=c(1,3),y=c(2,3))
x2<-data.frame(x=c(3,3),y=c(2,2))
df.list<-list(x1,x2)
kk<-do.call(rbind,df.list)
year<-data.frame(rep(c(1940,1941),c(nrow(x1),nrow(x2))))
names(year)<-"year"
mydata<-data.frame(cbind(kk,year))

 mydata
  x y year
1 1 2 1940
2 3 3 1940
3 3 2 1941
4 3 2 1941
```